# fullpage.js - Fp-auto-height middle section doesn't take its real height when click on anchor and moveTo() the last section

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I have 3 sections:

1. main with link
2. content section
3. contacts (that takes half of the page)

When initializing the library I set **scrollOverflow** to **true** so that when user scrolls the page, the content section will be scrolled normally.

By click on the link it is supposed to scroll to the contacts.
I use method: **fullpage_api.moveTo(3).**
But while scrolling (moving to 3 section), the content section is not scrolled and stays at the beginning of its content.

And after moving:

- the first half of the page is the beginning of the second section
- the second half is the contacts page.

**Supposed behaviour:**

- when the page is being scrolled to to the contacts after click, the content section will also be scrolled.

---

I have tried the folowing onclick-flow:

- destroy fullpage
- initialize it with **scrollOverflow: false**
- move to 3 section
- destroy fullpage
- initialize it with **scrollOverflow: true**

But after the last initialization the page jumps to the beginning.
And it is too crazy to be the best way.

---

For sure, there is a nice solution for such an ordinary case!

```
<div class="section">
  <a href="#contact">Click me</a>
</div>
<div class="section fp-auto-height">
  Height is more than one page
</div>
<div class="section fp-auto-height">
  Contact
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction of the issue [in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/ea17skjr)? It is difficult to understand what's your issue otherwise.

Comment: @alvaro, I have created the example [in your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7oqjzk3/2/). By click on "Move to 3" link you will be navigated to the 3 section, but the second one will not be scrolled. Hope this helps to understand the issue :)

Comment: Thanks for that.
fullPage.js doesn't currently provide any option to achieve that, but feel free to open an issue on the [fullpage.js issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues) and we can consider it for future releases.